# How to insert values that don't exist without syntax error?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, insert

I'm trying to add only values by ID that do not exist and I don't need to overwrite the existing ones.
Maybe someone could tell how to fix this?

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO coins VALUES (:id, :symbol, :current_price, :market_cap,) SELECT * FROM coins WHERE 'id' != :id",
          {'id': ids["id"], 'symbol': ids["symbol"], 'current_price': ids["current_price"], 'market_cap': ids["market_cap"]})
```

Comment: I want to clarify tho that the id is a string not an integer. And since this is a API get request I don't know exact value of the `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something as simple as this:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO coins VALUES (5, 'symbol', 'current_price', 'market_cap');
```

`id` just requires a corresponding `unique constraint` or `primary key constraint`.

Here's a test case:

[Working test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a5404e08553198343628ec9e4ffea9e7)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an exists insert query:

```sql
INSERT INTO coins (id, symbol, current_price, market_cap)
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM coins WHERE id = ?);
```

The Python code for this would be:

```py
sql = """
INSERT INTO coins (id, symbol, current_price, market_cap)
SELECT :id, :symbol, :current_price, :market_cap
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM coins WHERE id = :id)"""
c.execute(sql, {'id': ids["id"], 'symbol': ids["symbol"], 'current_price': ids["current_price"], 'market_cap': ids["market_cap"]})
```

Note that you might not even need to do this assuming that `id` already be a primary key or have a unique index on it.  In that case, any insert attempting to use a duplicate `id` would fail at the database level.